# Big Query Web UI Alter datatype of Table or empty table

Tags: google-bigquery, bigdata

I created a empty table , I m unable to alter the Datatype of the field from web ui, is there any command line or Alter table command for Altering the datatype from INTEGER -> STRING

Comment: You have a low rate. Important on SO, you have to mark accepted answers by using the tick on the left of the posted answer, below the voting. This will increase your rate. See how this works by visinting this link: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to recreate the schema, you cannot alter types.

If you want to copy the old data. Please make sure you create a temporary table, then once the schema is ready, you can query the old table and write to the new table making the transformation.

Comment: You need to recreate the schema, you cannot alter types. Sure will do that @Pentium10.

Comment: @Sabarish ok please read the meta link I posted above and mark accepted answers in your past questions too